# Including a matrix of math nodes in a TikZ figure in a minipage in a landscape in an afterpage

Tags: tikz-pgf, landscape, afterpage

I want to include a TikZ figure, containing a matrix of math nodes, displayed in landscape mode on its own page in my thesis, in such a way that the nominally surrounding text, which is in fact on the preceding page, is uninterrupted by the incorporation of my figure.

Here is a parody of what I've been doing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,british]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathtools,afterpage,rotating,pdflscape,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
DOGS

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{landscape}%
        \begin{figure}[h]%
            \caption{A charming tripartite diagram}%
            \label{fig:fig}%
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}[t]{.50\textwidth}  
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (0.5,0.5);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}      
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (0.5,0.5);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{.05\textwidth}  
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]
                    \matrix (m) 
                        [matrix anchor=orgn.center,
                        ampersand replacement=\&,
                        matrix of math nodes,
                        column sep={0.5cm,between origins},
                        row sep={.5cm,between origins},
                        inner sep=0cm] 
                        at (-0.25,-0.3) 
                    {
                        0 & 1\\
                        \node(orgn) {E_\infty};& 0\\
                    };
                    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (0.5,0.5);
                    \draw[line width=0.4mm] 
                        (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0)
                        (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5);
                    ;
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
\clearpage
}

HATS
\end{document}
```

The error engendered is thus: `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options`.

The code works if I *don't* include the matrix of math nodes—which, however, I need. The ampersand replacement is included because it's been suggested in seemingly related situations online, but it doesn't seem to help me to include it.

I should also note that this originally occurred in a chapter I had `\input` into a larger document, and when I do that, I get distinct errors, regarding math mode, ampersands, and carriage returns:

http://pastebin.com/y4bqFf6X.

I don't know if the same problems are causing both these errors, but wasn't sure how to provide a minimal example for the compound document.

How do I make it work?

Comment: If you say `ampersand replacement=\&`, you must use `\&` and not just `&` as a column separator in your `matrix`. After correcting the problem your code compiles for me. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ampersand replacement=\&` is used in a `\matrix` style, `\&` must be used as column separator inside `\matrix` declaration.

```
\matrix (m) [matrix anchor=orgn.center,
             ampersand replacement=\&,
             matrix of math nodes,
             column sep={0.5cm,between origins},
             row sep={.5cm,between origins},
             inner sep=0cm] 
            at (-0.25,-0.3) 
            {
             0 \& 1\\   %<---------------- & replaced by \&
             |(orgn)| E_\infty \& 0\\  %<---------------- & replaced by \&
             };
```

Side comment: all nodes from a `matrix of nodes` are named with `matrix_name-row-column`, but if an special name must be assigned to any node, syntax `|(name)|` does it. In OP's code `\node (orgn) {E_\infty}` can be replaced by `|(orgn)| E_\infty`.

[image]